# React : How to reset state value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am working on sorting . Actually it working fine I can sort data in `asc` and `desc` . I am using sorting for different fields. For example I have 5 fields in table if user want to sort data for field 1 and user click on next ( I am also using pagination ) , now let suppose user is on page 5 and user want to sort data for fields 2 here I want to reset the value of state to initial value ( Initial Value of state `val1=5` and `val2=0` ). How I will do this , I am new to ReactJS , Could someone please help me how I can fix this problem .

Sorry , If I made mistake in English Grammar because I am not native speaker .

**Code**

```
    sortingData= (ascValue,desValue) => {
this.setState(
   {
     dataSort:
     this.state.sortedData === ascValue? desValue: ascValue
   },
   () => {
     this.loadData();
   }
);
```

}

```
**Full Component Code**

    class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:8001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand what you want to do

Comment: @Maxwells.c . I updated my question , please have a look

Comment: @Maxwells.c Actually I am doing sorting for each fields of table . For example if user want to sort for field 1 in table he click on next to fetch more data in sorting data is fetching correctly but I want if User want to sort data for field 2 in table I want to reset the value of state which were increamented on next button

Comment: you want to reset the state of the pagination right? if yes just set an empty array for the itens on the state and then fetch the ordered items

Comment: Yes , When user click on other field that case I want to reset the value of state to initial value .. I am beginner Could you please  help me ?

Comment: Why are you calling getData() after sort? isn't it that it will replace your sorted data to whatever you get from API?

Comment: to reset the state, just use setState, passing the state it need to become (`setState({items: []})`

Comment: @TechTurtle Actually in getData() , I have I am getting data from server through API

Comment: @Maxwells.c Could you please write this in `sortHandler()` ? I think we will be do some condition for it

Comment: You can build a default search object include all the property you want to reset. And when the current field sort change like your case. Just assign that default object to the state.

Answer (score 1):

Better thing to do it to have state for all five data.

// In constructor

```
state = {
    dataSort: {
        data1: {sortedBy: asc, pagination: 1},
        data2: {sortedBy: asc, pagination: 1},
        data3: {sortedBy: asc, pagination: 1}, 
        data4: {sortedBy: asc, pagination: 1},
        data5: {sortedBy: asc, pagination: 1}
    }
}
```

// When updating sorting logic for particular data

```
this.setState({
    dataSort: {
        ...dataSort,
        data1: {
            sortBy: this.state.dataSort.data1 === val1? val2  : val1;
            pagination: 5
        }
    }
})
```

Now, if you want to reset then you can just change the pagination value or sortby value for particular data.

Comment: Sorting is working fine but I want to reset the value of State which is `Item` ,`skip` and `sortedData`